# IP Address Range for Swisscom Public Application Cloud

Tags: swisscomdev

I need to connect to a third party service API from a cloud foundry (Java) application running on Swisscom's public application cloud. This third party service is secured in a way that I need to provide the IP range I am using to connect to the service (for whitelisting purposes). What would that IP range be for Swisscom Public Application Cloud to outside services?

I could not find an answer in Swisscom's service documentation.

Comment: thanks for this guidance. will keep in mind for future posts

Comment: Ultimately this issues was downvoted and closed, because Swisscom is still asking it's customers to post support requests on StackOverflow, instead of providing a maintained support forum for their service offering elsewhere. Clearly there are instances, where posting on StackOverflow can be useful, but it shouldn't be a generic recommendation, because StackOverflow actually has fairly specific rules about what is ok to ask here. So, don't feel bad about getting this closed!

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but you want to make sure that the whitelisting is **not** your only line of defence, since everyone else on Swisscom's public cloud will share that IP address (range) with you and thus also be able to connect to that external service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's '194.209.222.199'. you can easily find out by opening a ssh tunnel to an app then curling a ip service (e.g. `curl ifconfig.co`).
Please note that this can change in the future but Swisscom would announce such a change first.